# Can someone please help translate this?

Tags: translation

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help translate this?

Comment: What did you do...don't tell me its a tattoo

Comment: No not mine . I'll never get something tattooed that I don't know the meaning to. They told me if I guessed what it said I'd win 50 bucks . 

Comment: hahaah just saying its a pretty bad tattoo job, what is he thinking hahahaha, the words are like written by a primary school kid

Comment: and im pretty sure the last two are names, lesley and dylan, the first one could be a name or the meaning vortex

Comment: Haha yes I know it looks bad too, thanks for the help . 

Answer (score 1):

It says:
渦流菜斯利迪化

渦 guo
流 liu
菜 cai
斯 si
利 li
迪 di
化 hua

I don't know what it is supposed to mean or why anyone would write that on their arm. Seems to say 'swirling current dish benefits/is good for Dihua'

迪化,dihua seems to be an old name for 乌鲁木齐 wulumuqi or Ürümqi in NW China

Comment: Can it be something meaning in Spanish ?

Comment: Transalated in Spanish?

Comment: `菜` -> `莱`, `化` -> `伦`.

Answer (score 1):

渦流（traditional Chinese）= 涡流（simplified Chinese): eddy current; vortex; vortex flow (via Bing dictionary).

> The apparatus finds some technical applications and is known as an "**eddy current** brake".
>
> 这种装置有某些技术上的应用，即众所周知的“**涡流**制动器。”
>
> via Bing dictionary

莱斯利: Leslie or Lesley, a western name written in Chinese following its pronunciation. 莱(lái) 斯(sī) 利(lì)

迪伦: Dylan, a western name written in Chinese following its pronunciation.  迪(dí) 伦(lún)

Comment: its no necessarily eddy current, its more like vortex

Comment: Maybe you're right. We don't know the context. I'll edit my answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

渦(wo)[wɜː]流(liu)[ljuː] seems also a pronounce of western name, I guess it maybe Will/Willie/Willis/Worley or other name, most like Worley['wɜ:li].

the explanation of 莱斯利 and 迪伦 are quite nice by @Wol

```
莱斯利：Leslie or Lesley, a western name written in Chinese by its' pronounce. 莱(lái) 斯(sī) 利(lì)

迪伦：Dylan, a western name written in Chinese by its' pronounce. 迪(dí) 伦(lún)
```

Answer (score 1):

渦流菜斯利迪化

means Chai Ser Li loves Di Lun

The 渦流 alone means vortex

Actually it part of the title of a famous song (1957) 
by Fang Qing Yin 方靜音
The song is 愛的渦流
"the vortex of love"